# Problem with embed Python plot in email showing blank

Tags: python, matplotlib, outlook, seaborn, pywin32

I'm trying to send an email with embedded plots with Python. I can't use "cid" to embed the plots due to the fact that some recipients won't be able to see them that way.

I tried to embed the plot via setting the property by SchemaName, but when I send the email the plot show as blank.

My code is the following:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.lineplot(x='Date', y='Total',hue = "Company", 
             data=df1)
plt.savefig('C:/MyDocs/Plot1.jpg')

sns.lineplot(x='Date', y='Total',hue = "City", 
             data=df2)
plt.savefig('C:/MyDocs/Plot2.jpg')

sns.lineplot(x='Date', y='Total',hue = "Name", 
             data=df3)
plt.savefig('C:/MyDocs/Plot3.jpg')

plot1 = 'C:/MyDocs/Plot1.jpg'
plot2 = 'C:/MyDocs/Plot2.jpg'
plot3 = 'C:/MyDocs/Plot3.jpg'

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = myemail
mail.Subject = Testing
attachment = mail.Attachments.Add(plot1, 0x5, 0, "display name1")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId")
attachment = mail.Attachments.Add(plot2, 0x5, 0, "display name2")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId2")
attachment = mail.Attachments.Add(plot3, 0x5, 0, "display name3")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId3")

html= ""</html>
<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=ES style='mso-ansi-language:ES'>Hello,<o:p></o:p></span></p>
Testing plots
<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=ES style='mso-ansi-language:ES'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<v:imagedata src='cid:"MyId"'/>
</v:shapetype><v:shape id="Imagen_x0020_1" o:spid="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75"
 alt="" style='width:482.25pt;height:321.75pt'>
<img width=643 height=429
src='cid:"MyId"' style='height:4.468in;width:6.697in'
v:shapes="Imagen_x0020_1"><![endif]></p>
<v:imagedata src='cid:"MyId2"'/>
</v:shapetype><v:shape id="Imagen_x0020_1" o:spid="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75"
 alt="" style='width:482.25pt;height:321.75pt'>
<img width=643 height=429
src='cid:"MyId2"' style='height:4.468in;width:6.697in'
v:shapes="Imagen_x0020_1"><![endif]></p>
<v:imagedata src='cid:"MyId3"'/>
</v:shapetype><v:shape id="Imagen_x0020_1" o:spid="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75"
 alt="" style='width:482.25pt;height:321.75pt'>
<img width=643 height=429
src='cid:"MyId3"' style='height:4.468in;width:6.697in'
v:shapes="Imagen_x0020_1"><![endif]></p>
</body>

</html>

mail.HTMLBody = html
mail.Send()
"""
```

But when I receive the email, the outline of the plots are there, but the plots show as blank. I've tried using base64 encoding but the same happens

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the sent and received messages with OutlookSpy (I am its author - click IMessage button) - is HTML body correct and have the right cids for the images? Is `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property set correctly on the attachments?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Is there a way to see that without OutlookSpy? I'm using a corporate PC so I can't install things

Comment: OutlookSpy can be installed without any admin rights - you can copy the appropriate dll (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/download/OutlookSpy.zip) to any folder and register it using regsvr32.exe. You can also use MFCMAPI (https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi), but it might be more challenging to navigate if you have never done so, plus you won't see OOM objects. only MAPI.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko thank you Dmitry. I was able to install OutlookSpy. I looked at PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID and it was ok to my knowledge. I got the HTML by doing the email manually and then saving that email as an HTML, should be ok. Can't seem to find why I can't embed the images correctly.

Comment: Look at the `PR_HTML` property in the IMessage window and/or click the Item button and select the `HTMLBody` property. What do you see for the img tags?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko it shows exactly the HTML as is in my Python code:  <v:imagedata src="Testing%20"_archivos/plot1.jpg"
  o:href="cid:MyId"/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img width=567 height=378
src="cid:MyId"
style='height:3.937in;width:5.906in' v:shapes="Imagen_x0020_2"><![endif]><span
lang=ES style='mso-ansi-language:ES'><o:p></o:p></span></p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature images use vml conditionals - you need to force the standard `img` tags instead of shape\imagedata. Replace `<!--[if gte vml 1]>` with `<!--[if gte vml 9]>` and `<![if !vml]>` with `<![if !vmlxyz]>` to disable the vml conditionals. It is crude, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding images is the most reliable way of transferring images between clients.

Outlook doesn't support Base64 encoded images as well as plots. You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.